# how to receive paypal payments on multiple accounts in asp.net mvc c# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing an application on asp.net MVC where admin is giving  e-commerce website on rent to vendors and they have their panels where they can add products an do other settings, all vendors will have their separate websites.
Here I need to integrate paypal payment method. If customer is buying anything from vendor1 the payment should be transfer in his account and if customer is buying anything from vendor2 then payment should be transfer in his account. But here in paypal we can receive payment to one account only whose **clientd** and **clientSecret** we have configured in our application.
Is there any way we can receive payment on different account (we will have email of that paypal account only).
I know how to integrate paypal on single account where receiver is only one on single application. But here I want multiple receiver on a single application.

Comment: Please note that on SO, you need to add what have you tried so far and what didn't work for you. You won't find an answer from scratch. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For full control, each vendor should generate their own clientid/secret via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , and copy paste this information into the configuration section of your site. This is the preferred setup.

For quicker onboarding of a new vendor, you can use the v2/orders `payee` field: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

You will have less control, and not be able to do refunds or capture authorizations for example.

Comment: i have used this method before for payments and it was working perfectly when i was depositing amount in account of Application owner (single account). well i have added payee and it is giving me exceptions now!

Comment: i was using payment class for making payments and payment.create() for creating payment. when i added payee it gives exception.
exception detail :{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"fd337820c0824"}

tried the link but couldnt help!

Comment: where as the code link you have provided i have tried but couldn't help!

Comment: Well you are doing something wrong; read the documentation more closely and debug your problem.

Comment: i have read it and applied it! but request is not answering!
i am using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Core PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders two SDK 
from this link
 https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK
but the request is not answering!
before that i was using Paypal.api sdk payment.create method that is giving me error

Comment: i wish i could share my code snippet, but comment section is not allowing because of limited characters

Answer (score 0):

we have the same goal. We use paypal checkout sdk for PHP. Since we saw this documentation

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

but it seems it's not working when we create an order. When we add this line of code

```
    array(
       'payee' => array(
           'email_address' => 'payee@email.com'
       )
    )
```

Comment: yeah! i have also tried it in my c# application request is not answering!!